# react-native: File android/java_pid14920.hprof is 311.59 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit

Tags: android, react-native, github, hprof

I would like to push my project into the github, however i just notice there is a file called **java_pid14920.hprof** inside the android folder and cause around 300MB

`remote: error: File android/java_pid14920.hprof is 301.75 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB`

I wonder it is safe to delete this file ?

Comment: Can you find a solution?

Comment: Short answer is YES. You can (and prolly should) delete the Heap Dump File (.hprof). More info here in the [Oracle Docs.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/clopts001.html)

Answer (score 48):

The only answer here didn't work for me, but I found a solution that did.

My offending file was `android/java_pid2325.hprof`, but yours obviously may vary. I used `git filter-branch`:

`git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch android/java_pid2325.hprof'`

Make sure to add `*.hprof` to your `.gitignore` and push the commit.

Note*-> Make sure to **change the name** of  *.hprof to the same as your local *.hprof

Comment: Thrilled to help! @RizwanIjaz

Comment: Thank you so much, its the best answer worked for me.

Comment: please how to add *.hprof to .gitignore ? I have 4 hprof files, do I add them all to gitignore ?

Comment: @zedArt
solution courtesy of Hyeomin

Go to ".gitignore"

Just put this snippet.

*.hprof

Save .gitignore file.

Answer (score 31):

This sounds like a heap profiling output file, which you probably don't want in your repository at all.  You'll want to delete it from the entire history and probably add an entry to `.gitignore` to ignore `*.hprof`.  If the file is not in the latest commit, simply deleting it there won't make your repository pushable to GitHub; you'll have to remove the object from the entire history.

If you can easily find the commit which introduced it (try `git log -- android/java_pid14920.hprof`), you can do a `git rm android/java_pid14920.hprof` and then do `git commit --fixup HASH-OF-COMMIT && GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=true git rebase -ir --autosquash HASH-OF-COMMIT^` (note the caret) to rebase out the file.

You can also use a tool like `git filter-branch` or `bfg` to filter out large objects that you don't want.

Note that doing this will rewrite the history of any intervening commits, changing their object IDs.

Answer (score 8):

I ran this command. It works on Windows 10

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch android/java_pid10213.hprof"
```

- Use **"** instead of **'**

Answer (score 5):

@bk2204 answer worked for me.
In my case, .hprof files were in android/hprof.

1. Go to ".gitignore"
2. Just put this snippet.

android/

*.hprof

3. Save .gitignore file.

Comment: I have manually deleted the hprof file. 
Then I ran `git clean -f`
and tried pushing again. 
But, I keep getting the error message.
Any workaround for this ?

Comment: But commit is already done, putting into .gitignore will work from next commit.

Comment: My problem was that I couldn't commit because of hprof size. So I put this line before I commit and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I had two hpprof files committed;
So I just ran this command, and the files have been removed successfully.

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch android/java_pid21295.hprof android/java_pid16516.hprof'
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch example/android/java_pid2243.hprof"
```

Then

```
git push -u origin main
```

Note:

My file was present in the directory like this.

```
example/android/java_pid2243.prof
```