# React Native: .hprof file exceeds GitHub's 100MB file size limit

Tags: react-native, github, filesize, hprof, upload-max-filesize

I'm trying to push my React Native app to GitHub, and I'm getting several errors like the following:

```
remote: error: File android/java_pid1566.hprof is 667.24 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58646396/react-native-file-android-java-pid14920-hprof-is-311-59-mb-this-exceeds-github) and it suggested running `git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch android/java_pid1566.hprof'`, then adding a `*.hprof` line to `.gitignore`, then redoing `git add`, `git commit`, and `git push`. However, I still got the same error.

Does anyone know how I can approach this?