# React Native: getting hprof file too big error even when file isn't present

Tags: android, git, react-native, gitignore

When I try to run `git push origin master` in my React Native app, I get

```
file android/java_pid60072.hprof is 564.94 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

even though `android/java_pid60072.hprof` doesn't exist in my project. I tried adding `*.hprof` to my `.gitignore` and running `git filter-branch --index-filter` as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330771/git-lfs-this-exceeds-githubs-file-size-limit-of-100-00-mb).

Why might these files be mentioned by Git when they don't exist, and how can I resolve this?

Comment: This solution worked for me. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64084214/12603213)

Answer (score 0):

> Why might these files be mentioned by Git when they don't exist, and how can I resolve this?

They might not exist in your current commit / worktree, but they exist somewhere in your history. You can do `git log -- android/java_pid60072.hprof` to display the commits touching that file.

If you use it correctly, you can indeed use `git filter-branch` to remove this file from your history, but as you didn't supply the whole command you used it is impossible to say why it didn't work. Or if the command you supplied is the complete command, then it explains that it didn't work as it is not correct for your use-case.

Alternatively, if the `git log` just displays few commits that touches the file, for example because you just once added it accidentally and then didn't touch it anymore, you can also use the much simpler `git rebase --interactive` to remove the file from your history.

Let's assume the `git log` above shows that commit `5981c6312c65dae928f2f34311202cd93b9000d8` added the file and is the only commit touching the file, then you could simply do `git rebase --interactive 5981c6312c65dae928f2f34311202cd93b9000d8~`, then modify the todo-list that opens by adding after the `pick 5981c63` line a line reading

```
exec git rm android/java_pid60072.hprof && git commit --amend -C HEAD
```

Then save and close the todo-list and after the rebase is finished, your history should be cleaned and you should be able to push.